# Rails creating multiple records in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been at this for hours now but can't find a solution and am now wondering if I'm approaching this correctly.

I have an `employee` form and in it I'm creating multiple `ee_pay` records (which store a reference to the `company_pay` type they are). The problem is accessing the `company_pay` associated with the `ee_pay` that I'm creating in the form.

The code below works but I keep getting the description of the second `@taxable_pays` type in the variable `@description` in `_pay_types.html.erb`

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening. I've tried multiple ways of passing the description of each one. I know there's two in that collection because the correct ids are getting stored in two separate `ee_pay` records that get saved when I submit the form.

Can anyone tell me how I can pass the value of each `@taxable_pays.description` to the view? And also tell me if I'm approaching this in the best way?

Thanks for looking. Here's my code:

> **employees_controller.rb**

I have a before_action that does the following:

```
@taxable_pays = CompanyPay.where(company_id: current_company.id).order(:id)
```

Then:

```
  def new
    @taxable_pays.each do |pt|
    pay_type = @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)
    @description = pt.description
  end
```

> **_form.html.erb**

```
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">  
            <div class="form_label"><strong>Description</strong></div>           
          </div> 
          <div class="col-md-4">  
            <div class="form_label"><strong>Amount</strong></div>           
          </div> 
          <div class="col-md-4">  
            <div class="form_label"><strong>Rate</strong></div>           
          </div> 

            <%= f.fields_for :ee_pay do |builder| %>
              <%= render "pay_types", :f => builder %>              
            <% end %>                 

      </div>
```

> **_pay_types.html.erb**

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_indent1"><%= @description %></div></div>
    <div class="form_spacer"></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form_indent1"><%= f.text_field :amount, class: "number_input" %></div>
    <div class="form_spacer"></div>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-md-4">  
    <div class="form_indent1"><%= f.text_field :rate, class: "number_input" %></div>
    <div class="form_spacer"></div><br />
  </div>
```

> ***Edit 1 (updated)***

After advice from Mark G. below my code now looks like:-

> **employees_controller.rb**

```
  @pay_types = []
  @taxable_pays.each do |pt|
    @pay_types << @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)
    puts "Debug for the pay_types"
    puts @pay_types
  end
```

> **_form.html.erb**

```
    <div>
      <% @pay_types.each do |ee_pay| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :ee_pay do |builder| %>
          <%= render "pay_types", :f => builder, :ee_pay => ee_pay %>              
        <% end %>                 
      <% end %> 
    </div>
```

> **_pay_types.html.erb**

```
    <%= f.hidden_field :company_pay_id %>  (not on original edit)

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_indent1"><%= ee_pay.company_pay.description %></div></div>
      <div class="form_spacer"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form_indent1"><%= f.text_field :amount, class: "number_input" %></div>
      <div class="form_spacer"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form_indent1"><%= ee_pay.company_pay.units %></div>
      <div class="form_spacer"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4">  
      <div class="form_indent1"><%= f.text_field :rate, class: "number_input" %></div>
      <div class="form_spacer"></div><br />
    </div>
```

I originally thought this was each of the @pay_types printing twice but looking at it again it's the `description` printing twice, each time with each of the `company_pay_id`s

```
*description*        *company_pay_id*    
Basic                   2
Basic                   8
Time & 1/2              2
Time & 1/2              8
```

I'm really stumped with this.

> ***Edit 2***

This is the console output I'm getting when I try create a new employee

```
        CompanyPay Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "company_pays".* FROM "company_pays"  WHERE "company_pays"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
          Rendered employees/_pay_types.html.erb (2.8ms)
        Debug in the _form view fields_for
        #<EePay:0x007f4130a214a8>
          Rendered employees/_pay_types.html.erb (0.5ms)
        Debug in the _form view fields_for
        #<EePay:0x007f4130a214a8>
          CompanyPay Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "company_pays".* FROM "company_pays"  WHERE "company_pays"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
          Rendered employees/_pay_types.html.erb (2.4ms)
        Debug in the _form view fields_for
        #<EePay:0x007f4130a1fcc0>
          Rendered employees/_pay_types.html.erb (0.7ms)
        Debug in the _form view fields_for
        #<EePay:0x007f4130a1fcc0>
          Rendered employees/_form.html.erb (37.5ms)
          Rendered employees/new.html.erb within layouts/application (38.3ms)
```

I'm giving up for the night. Been looking at it for too long and getting nowhere. Thanks for the help. Will try again tomorrow

Comment: What's the contents of the `@pay_types` collection?  Is that length 2 or 4?  Your code looks syntactically correct, so I would start checking your variable values and see whats causing the extra iterations.  You can use `logger.info` in your controller to do some primitive debugging.

Comment: I've debugged `@pay_types` and in the terminal it's showing that there's 2 objects with different references `#<EePay:0x007f41307346c8>
#<EePay:0x007f4130732828>`. I'm banging my head off the wall here. Just can't see the reason for rendering twice for each object in `@pay_types`. Would showing you the generated html be any use?

Comment: If you remove the `fields_for` tag and just try rendering the partial without the form fields, do you still get duplicates?  If that still happens, try naming the partial something else and see if it still occurs?

Comment: Tried that - replaced all the content in `_pay_types.html.erb` with random text and removed the `fields_for` from `_form.html.erb`.  The partial only rendered twice which is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went around in circles with this using Mark's method so asked another question on stackoverflow which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411934/rails-nested-attributes-being-duplicated/28412031?noredirect=1#comment45161113_28412031). This might help someone else who lands here.

Basically, the code should be:-

> **employees_controller**

```
@taxable_pays.each do |tp|
  @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: tp.id)
end
```

> **_form**

```
<%= f.fields_for :ee_pay do |builder| %>
   <%= render "pay_types", :f => builder %>    
<% end %>
```

> **_pay_types**

```
    <div class="row">
        <%= f.hidden_field :company_pay_id %> 
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_indent1"><%= f.object.company_pay.description %></div></div>
          <div class="form_spacer"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-10">         
            <div class="col-md-4">  
              <div class="form_indent1"><%= f.text_field :rate, class: "number_input" %></div>
              <div class="form_spacer"></div><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form_indent1"><%= f.text_field :amount, class: "number_input" %></div>
              <div class="form_spacer"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Notice how in the `_pay_types` partial, the `company_pay` associated with the `ee_pay` being built can be accessed using `<%= f.object.company_pay.description %>`, as long as all the associations are set up correctly. So simple.

Answer (score 1):

In the example code you gave above, `@description` is an instance variable on your controller.  It looks like you're iterating over all your `@taxable_pays` objects and assigning `@description` within that loop, so the value of `@description` is always going to be whatever the *last* taxable pay's description is.

Conceptually, it looks like you're trying to do the right thing, but I think you might be making it more complicated than it needs to be.  It looks like `ee_pay` is associated to `CompanyPay` right?  Why not in your `_pay_types.html.erb` file, just go through the association that you've established?

```
<div class="form_indent1"><%= ee_pay.company_pay.description %></div>
```

Since you don't have the `ee_pay` variable available to your partial, you'll need to pass that to your partial in `_form.html.erb`.  Also, how are you generating multiple sets of form fields without looping over the `ee_pay` collection?  I would picture it working something like (naming seems a bit confusing, but just going with what you had):

**controller**

```
def new
  @pay_types = []
  @taxable_pays.each do |pt|
    @pay_types << @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<% @pay_types.each do |ee_pay| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :ee_pay do |builder| %>
    <%= render "pay_types", :f => builder, :ee_pay => ee_pay %>              
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Let me know if that doesn't work and we can tweak things until you get something that solves your particular problem.

Comment: Yes I was generating multiple sets of form fields without looping over any collections. I was puzzled myself as to exactly how that was happening but I put it down to the code in my `employees_controller` where I have `@taxable_pays.each do |pt| pay_type = @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)`. I'm going to give your code a go now

Comment: Got it working with your code but it's rendering each new `ee_pay` twice (similar to what it was doing for me previously i.e. it magically rendered the two new `ee_pay` nested forms without me iterating over anything). So now I have 4 nested records. Any ideas? I'll have a mess around with it myself too. Thanks for your help. Much apprecaited

Comment: I'm also struggling when editing a previously created form with these multiple nested records. It's duplicating loads and creating multiple entries when I edit one of the nested records.

Comment: Is it rendering the partial 'pay_types' multiple times or is it doing the 'fields_for' multiple times?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to check that. I've been looking at it all day trying to figure out what it's doing but am getting nowhere. I'll put debug into the view code (I had some earlier but removed it) and edit my original post in a few

Comment: I'm going to edit my `Edit 1` above to show a line I somehow didn't post and the resulting output in the format I'm seeing. It indicates that each time this `@taxable_pays.each do |pt|
      @pay_types << @employee.ee_pay.build` executes it's creating two new `ee_pay` objects (which both appear to be referenced by `#<EePay:0x007f41307346c8>` I'm giving up for the night. Thanks for helping Mark G. I'll hopefully sort it tomorrow