# Rails Nested attributes being duplicated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

This problem has beaten me. I've  been at it all weekend but can't figure out what is happening.

When I create a new `employee` object, I also want to create multiple new `ee_pay` records using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ee_pay` in my `employee` model.

Creation of `ee_pay` records for new employees is dependent on the amount of `company_pay` objects that exist for the company that the employee belongs to. So in the case below there's 2 `company_pay` objects -> "Basic" [id:2] and "Time + 1/2" [id:3] (returned in the `before_action`) and I want to create an `ee_pay` for each of these for the employee in question

Here's the code:-

> **employees_controller.rb**

```
 before_action :set_company_pay_types, only: [:new, :update, :edit]

        def new
            @ee_pay_types = []
            @taxable_pays.each do |pt|
              @ee_pay_types << @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)
            end
        end                 

        private
          def set_company_pay_types
              @taxable_pays = CompanyPay.where(['company_id = ? AND pay_sub_head_id = ? AND description <> ?', current_company.id, 1, "Salary"]).order(:id)
          end

          def employee_params
            params.require(:employee).permit(....[multiple other fields]..., address_attributes:[:id, :line1, :line2, :line3, :line4, :postcode, :country], ee_pay_attributes:[:id, :employee_id, :company_pay_id, :amount, :rate])
          end
```

> **views/employees/_form**

```
<div><strong>Hourly Pay Types</strong></div>
<div class="form_spacer"></div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">  
      <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_label"><strong>Description</strong></div></div>           
   </div> 
   <div class="col-md-3">  
      <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_label"><strong>Amount</strong></div></div>           
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">  
      <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_label"><strong>Units</strong></div></div>           
   </div>                
   <div class="col-md-4">  
      <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_label"><strong>Rate</strong></div></div>           
   </div> 
   <div>
             <%= debug @ee_pay_types %> 
             <% @ee_pay_types.each do |ee_pay| %>
                 <%= f.fields_for :ee_pay do |builder| %>                                   
                 <%= builder.hidden_field :company_pay_id %>     
                 <div class="col-md-3">
                     <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_indent1"><%= ee_pay.company_pay.description %></div></div>
                     <div class="form_spacer"></div>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="col-md-3">
                     <div class="form_indent1"><%= builder.text_field :amount, class: "number_input" %></div>
                     <div class="form_spacer"></div>
                 </div>  
                 <div class="col-md-2">
                     <div class="form_indent1"><%= ee_pay.company_pay.units %></div>
                     <div class="form_spacer"></div>
                 </div>  
                 <div class="col-md-4">  
                     <div class="form_indent1"><%= builder.text_field :rate, class: "number_input" %></div>
                     <div class="form_spacer"></div><br />
                 </div>                             

                 <% end %> 
             <% end %> 
   </div> 
   </div>
```

> **Output from employees/new**

When I go to create a new employee record, I'm getting the following output for the `ee_pay` objects. It turns out the code is duplicating each one in the following format:-

```
*description*        *company_pay_id*    
Basic                   2
Basic                   3
Time & 1/2              2
Time & 1/2              3
```

[image: output from employees/new]

It looks to me like this line `@ee_pay_types << @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)` in the `employees_controller` is building two new `ee_pay` objects (that are output in the debug in the picture above). Then in the view, it's iterating over these two and for each one, creating two new `ee_pay` objects. I think this is what's happening but I could be completely wring. I'm lost at this stage and I've no idea how to fix it.

Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction on how to solve it. It's probably something very obvious that I'm missing.

Thanks for looking

> **Edit 1**

Adding the models as requested

> **models/ee_pay**

```
    class EePay < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :employee
        belongs_to :company_pay
    end
```

> **model/company_pay**

```
    class CompanyPay < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :pay_sub_head
        belongs_to :company
        has_many :ee_pay
    end
```

> **model/employee**

```
    class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :company
        belongs_to :address
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
        has_many :ee_pay
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :ee_pay
    end
```

Yann suggested in the comments changing the `employee_controller` to this

```
    @ee_pay_types = []
    @taxable_pays.each do |pt|
        @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)
    end
```

and removing the iteration over `@ee_pay_types` in the view, which now looks like (I changed any reference to `ee_pay` to `builder`):-

```
    <div>
            <%= debug @ee_pay_types %>  
            <%= f.fields_for :ee_pay do |builder| %>                                    
                <%= builder.hidden_field :company_pay_id %>     

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_indent1"><%= builder.company_pay.description %></div></div>
                    <div class="form_spacer"></div>
                </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form_indent1"><%= builder.text_field :amount, class: "number_input" %></div>
                    <div class="form_spacer"></div>
                </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form_indent1"><%= builder.company_pay.units %></div>
                    <div class="form_spacer"></div>
                </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-4">  
                    <div class="form_indent1"><%= builder.text_field :rate, class: "number_input" %></div>
                    <div class="form_spacer"></div><br />
                </div>
            <% end %> 
    </div>
```

But this gives me the error:-

```
undefined method `company_pay' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f47d5649118>
```

To me it looks like I can't access the `company_pay` of the `ee_pay` being created. Anyone any ideas?

> **Edit 2 - Solved**

After making the edits suggested by Yan Foto, I was then able to access the `company_pay` of the `ee_pay` being created using `builder.object.company_pay.description`. Thanks again Yan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate before [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) since it renders your form for the number of existing associations. You can confirm this by changing the number of `@taxable_pays` to 3 and see how you get 9 (and not 6) items in your form.

Change your controller to the following:

```
def new
  @ee_pay_types = []
  @taxable_pays.each do |pt|
    @employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)
  end
end
```

and remove `<% @ee_pay_types.each do |ee_pay| %>` from your form and you're good to go.

**Update**
*You also wanted to access `CompanyPay` in the form:*

`builder.object` gives you access to the form object (`EePay` instance) and calling `builder.object.company_pay.description` gives you the description of the associated `CompanyPay`.

Comment: I tried what you're suggesting over the weekend but the problem is that I couldn't figure out how to access the related `company_pay` that's associated with the `ee_pay`  being built - I want to access it in order to get it's `description`. The company_pay_id of the newly built `ee_pay` is being defined in `@employee.ee_pay.build(company_pay_id: pt.id)`. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlD please add your models and update the question. Its hard to say anything at the moment!

Comment: You just need to access the form object, which is gonna be an `EePay` as follows: `builder.object`. Now you can also access the `CompanyPay`: `builder.object.company_pay.description`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556359/how-to-get-at-the-underlying-object-inside-a-rails-form-or-field-for-block) for another example.

Comment: You are an absolute saint. This has been killing me. Thank you so much

Comment: I am really flattered. So glad that I could help!

Comment: Yan do you know if it's possible to display `fields_for` in different places of the view for each object to be created? So in above case I'm creating 2 objects but lets say I had another piece of code in the `employees_controller/new` method that also built an `ee_pay` object. How would I go about rendering the first 2 objects together, then the third object in a separate place? As soon as I put the `fields_for` in the view it renders all 3 objects together? Thanks again

Comment: The fastest way would be to use `builder.index` to get the index of current object being rendered and if its bigger than a predefined number then bypass rendering the form. There may be better solutions though...